# angular enable Ivy cause problem building library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-ivy

## Problem

I have created a angular workplace which contain one application and a library. After I enable IVY, I got an error while building the library. But it runs fine If I set enableIvy to false.

## Code

tsconfig.json

```
 {
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "cxi-library": ["dist/cxi-library"],
      "cxi-library/*": ["dist/cxi-library/*"]
  }
},
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

part of angular.json

```
  "cxi-library": {
        "projectType": "library",
        "root": "projects/cxi-library",
        "sourceRoot": "projects/cxi-library/src",
        "prefix": "lib",
        "architect": {
          "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
            "options": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/cxi-library/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "project": "projects/cxi-library/ng-package.json"
            }
          },
          "test": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
            "options": {
              "main": "projects/cxi-library/src/test.ts",
              "tsConfig": "projects/cxi-library/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "karmaConfig": "projects/cxi-library/karma.conf.js"
            }
          },
          "lint": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
            "options": {
              "tsConfig": [
               "projects/cxi-library/tsconfig.lib.json",
                "projects/cxi-library/tsconfig.spec.json"
              ],
              "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

tried to **run ng build cxi-library**
error received as below:

** It is not recommended to publish Ivy libraries to NPM repositories **

Building entry point 'cxi-library'

---

Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:/cxi.registry.ui/cxi.registry.ui/C:/cxi.registry.ui/cxi.registry.ui/dist/cxi-library/cxi-library.d.ts'
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:/cxi.registry.ui/cxi.registry.ui/C:/cxi.registry.ui/cxi.registry.ui/dist/cxi-library/cxi-library.d.ts'
See "C:\Users\JUNXIL~1.FOX\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-tIrBUR\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. It was because I did not build my library with the "--prod" option.

```
ng build my-lib --prod
```

Maybe this will help someone...

#### EDIT

Notice that the "--prod" flag sets the compiler option "enableIvy" to false. So if you install the dependency, you may need to call the Angular compatibility compiler. You may want to use a postinstall script for this:

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "ngcc"
}
```

source: https://angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility